# ng-click function is not working on tabs in AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hello sir i have to call function for get the list of albums but in my case ng-click is not working no action will be performed what's wrong in my code?

```js
 //Our controller code here
  /**
  * @Summary: getAlbumsBySellerUserTypeKeyId function, get the productsAlbum list
  * @param: NA
  * @return: allAlbums
  * @Description:
  */ 
 $scope.allAlbums = [];
 $scope.sellerUserTypeKeyId = [];
 $scope.getAlbumsBySellerUserTypeKeyId = function() {
  //Enable class fadeAndDisable call the getAlbumsBySellerUserTypeKeyId() function
  $("#loadingAlbums").toggleClass("fadeAndDisable", true);
  
  $scope.sellerUserTypeKeyId = Number(AUTH.userTypeKeyId);
  var PRODUCT_DB_REF = firebase.database().ref('datastore/productsAlbum');
 
  
  //Re-enable class fadeAndDisable after response is received
  $("#loadingAlbums").toggleClass("fadeAndDisable", false);
  
  PRODUCT_DB_REF.orderByChild("sellerUserTypeKeyId").equalTo($scope.sellerUserTypeKeyId)
  .on("value", function(snapshot) {
    var value = snapshot.val();
    if(value != null) {
    $scope.allAlbums = objToArray(value);
    //USED FOR SET THE ALBUM LENGTH IN THE ALBUM TABS SECTION
    $rootScope.allAlbums = $scope.allAlbums;
    }
  });
 }
```

```html
    <li class="ng-cloak">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="openPageTab(event, 'createAlbum')"
        ng-click="getAlbumsBySellerUserTypeKeyId()">
        Album
      <span ng-if="allAlbums.length > 0">({{allAlbums.length}})</span> 
    </a>
    </li>
```

Comment: Why do you have onclick and ng-click together?

Comment: sir because i have multiple tabs that's the reason i am using onclick if tabs will  be change different-different page will be loaded?

Comment: You may have to rewrite all your code to one particular style. Use either angular or jquery . Don't mix both

Comment: @Vivz sir, i don't understand please explain me?

Comment: Can you post the function openPageTab() ? Also - do you see any errors on console? what exactly not working when you click?

Comment: Ok sir. i will post the function.no sir i have no error is show in console and i have to get the list from the firebaseDB ?

Comment: As @Vivz mentioned, don't use `onclick` and `ng-click` together.  Second Don't mess-up your code with jQuery, you can do it using angular only.

Comment: ok sir so tell me any another  way for fix this  problem?

Comment: please anybody give me any solution for that issue?